# Rstudio ignore the R path I manually set but use the deleted one

Tags: r, rstudio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACoCs.png)

Even I export the R path to be the correct one, rstudio still use the deleted R path.

I checked my ~/.bashrc file and the deleted path is not in $PATH variable...

Comment: R does not use the same PATH as bash. You can change your R path with the `.Rprofile` file. See `?Startup` However this looks to be a problem with basic setup since it appears you asked where RStudio thinks R is but you are able to launch R from a NIX console session. When I use that echo command I get `_R`. Really need much better description of your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , thanks for user 42's answer. 
However, I can't find where is .Rprofile located and I've made too many changes to configuration files that it's hard to pinpoint where's the problem any more. I completely erase my disk division and reinstall ubuntu.

My system is ubuntu server so I try to install everything just as user rather than root. And specifically I install R, R-essentials using conda in the directory /usr. This time the Rstudio can find R without problem. Therefore I think Rstudio can only find R in certain directories... like /bin /usr/bin. And somehow it ignores R in other directories.